# How to convert a Mysql INSERT into PHP array to insert in loop?

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `login`) VALUES(1, 'test1'), (2, 'test2'),  (3, 'test3'), (4, 'test4'), (5, 'test5')
```

How can I convert this simple insert into a php array to make inserts in loop with my if conditions?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It's really to difficult to tell what your actual problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that with below;

```
$values = array(
     '1' => 'test1',
     '2' =>'test2',
     '3' => 'test3', 
     '4' => 'test4',
     '5' => 'test5'
     );

 $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `login`) VALUES";
 foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
    $sql .= "(" . $k . ", '" . $v . "')";
 }
```

If you provide more details with "your if conditions", it will be updated

Comment: This would only work with a single result as no comma delimitation is present. With one result, there would be no reason for the loop either. See my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Huseyin was pretty close, but I modified the code as you would end up with no comma's to delimit your inserts, which are required.

To counter this, you can collect the values inside of an array, then use implode() to add the comma's in the mysql.

```
$values = array#
(
    "1" => 'test1',
    "2" => 'test2',
    "3" => 'test3', 
    "4" => 'test4',
    "5" => 'test5',
);

$collect = array();

foreach ($values as $k => $v) 
{
    $collect[] = "(" . $k . ", '" . $v . "')";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `login`) VALUES " . implode(", ", $collect);
```